# How to update the Fore.Color of Label when its Text Changed ...by C# Code in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, winforms

I have dynamic Content for a Label in WPF. How can I change the foreground color of a label when text of the label changed, I have the code for Winform but I need it for WPF..
Winform Code in Designer Side

```
this.lblSolar.Name= "lblSolar";
this.lblSolar.TextChanged + = new System.EventHandler(this.LblSolar_TextChanged);
```

Code of text_Changed function

```
private void LblSolar_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var solarCurrent= Convert.ToDouble(_sValues[(int)ValueOfRTC.SupplyCurrent]);
if (supplyCurrent < 1)
{
lblSupply.ForeColor= Color.Yellow;
}
else
{
// Assigning other colors.....
}
}
```

But I couldn't found "TextChanged" Property in WPF XAML.. then what is the Solution?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use TextBox instead of Label

vb.net

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    TextBox1.Foreground = Brushes.Yellow
End Sub
```

C#

```
 private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
    TextBox1.Foreground = Brushes.Yellow;
}
```

Comment: why do you need a label?

Answer (score 2):

In WPF a Label is not only a control to present Text. 
It is a ContentPresenter that can display all kinds of controls other than text as well. Thus it has no text changend event.
Generally speaking you should not use events in the same manner when using WPF as you did with winforms. You should really consider to start lerning MVVM pattern as it will make your life a lot easier in a long term (after a rough start).

However if you insist in usng events to do this you NEED to use a Textbox...BUT you can make the textbox look like a label like this:

```
this.lblSolar.Name= "lblSolar";
this.lblSolar.TextChanged + = new System.EventHandler(this.LblSolar_TextChanged);
this.lblSolar.BorderThickness = 0;
this.lblSolar.Background = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
this.lblSolar.IsReadOnly = True;
```

Answer (score 1):

What Denis said is right. If you still want to achieve this with Label, you can simply derive your own label control that provides a ContentChanged event like this.

```
public class MyLabel : Label
{
    static MyLabel()
    {
        ContentProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyLabel),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnContentChanged)));
    }

    private static void OnContentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyLabel lbl = d as MyLabel;
        if (lbl.ContentChanged != null)
        {
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args = new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs( ContentProperty, e.OldValue, e.NewValue);
            lbl.ContentChanged(lbl, args);
        }
    }

    public event DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler ContentChanged;
}
```

You can use this in XAML like this.

```
<local:MyLabel Content="Sample" ContentChanged="MyLabel_ContentChanged"/>
```